# Can't get the public IP of a connected client on my server

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, ngrok, python-sockets

I have a very basic server written in Python as follows:

```py
import socket
from time import sleep
import requests

c = None #Client socket1
addr = None #Client address1
    
server_socket1 = socket.socket() #by default it is SOCK_STREAM (TCP) and has porotocal AF_INET (IPv4) 

server_socket1.bind(('127.0.0.1',9999)) #server machine's ip and port on which it will send and recieve connections from

server_socket1.listen(2) #We will only accept two connections as of now , one for each client
print("Server started successfully!!!")
print("Waiting for connections...\n\n")

while (((c is None)and(addr is None))):
    if((c is None) and (addr is None)):
        c,addr = server_socket1.accept()
        print("Intrusion detected at address 127.0.0.1:9999 ")
        print("Client connected with ip address "+str(addr))
        client_ip=str(addr)

        
while True:
    msg = c.recv(4096)
    if(msg!=None):
        #print(msg)
        headers, sep, body = msg.partition(b'\r\n\r\n')
        headers = headers.decode('utf-8') 
        print(headers)

        html_body = "<html><body><h1>You are not authorized to acces this Page!</p><br><p>3 more attemps and your ip will be jailed!</p></body></html>"
        response_headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html; encoding=utf8',
        'Content-Length': len(html_body),
        'Connection': 'close',
        }

        response_headers_raw = ''.join('%s: %s\r\n' % (k, v) for k, v in response_headers.items())
        response_proto = 'HTTP/1.1'
        response_status = '200'
        response_status_text = 'OK' # this can be random

        # sending all this stuff
        r = '%s %s %s\r\n' % (response_proto, response_status, response_status_text)
        c.sendall(r.encode())
        c.sendall(response_headers_raw.encode())
        c.sendall(b'\r\n') # to separate headers from body
        c.send(html_body.encode(encoding="utf-8"))
```

I have then used ngrok to forward my port 9999 on the web. Then I execute the server.

Now, when I connect to the ngrok's provided link via my mobile phone, I get the response from my server, that is a single lined HTML content, as seen in the code itself.

But, the `c,addr = socket.accept()` should return the IP of the connected client. In my case, I have used my phone to connect to ngrok, which should use my phone's public IP to connect to it, still on my server side, it shows something like this:

[image]

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `listen(2)` doe not accomplish 'we will only accept two connections as of now'. That's not what it's for. And your code only accepts one connection. And you don't need to test the same condition twice in a row. You can remove the `if` inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks a lot to clear things up for the listen() part. While, for the condition testing part, I took this block of code from my another project and forgot to remove it. Thanks for informing that as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing makes perfect sense, as the phone is not directly connected to your server (it can't be, since your server is listening on `127.0.0.1` aka localhost, so it can only accept connections that originate from the same machine).

The phone is connected to ngrok, and then ngrok is connected to your server. So you are seeing the IP that ngrok is connecting to your server from.  There is simply no way for your server to get the IP of the phone, unless ngrok includes the phone's IP in the HTTP request it sends to your server, such as in an `X-Forwarded-For`, `X-Original-Forwarded-For`, `X-Real-IP`, etc kind of request header, which are common for proxies to send (but which I don't see in your screenshot, but it is incomplete).

```
---------     ---------     ----------
| phone | <-> | ngrok | <-> | server |
---------     ---------     ----------
           ^             ^
           |             |
desired IP is here   but you are getting IP from here
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for this detailed answer. I was very much confused of what was exactly happening but you cleared my doubts. Can you please suggest me, what should i do to be able to capture the public IP of my phone?

Comment: @PriyanshGupta unless ngrok adds the phone's IP to the request it sends to your server (you are printing the headers, do you see the phone's IP listed?) , or the phone adds its own IP to the request it sends to ngrok, then there is simply no way for your server to get the phone's IP